# Is there an ideal value for the difference between the stick fixed and stick free static margin?

Tags: stability, elevator

I'm calculating the static stability for a fictional  aircraft and have to determine the elevator size. I have all the calculations but don't know how to choose the correct size and position. Is it ideal to have the difference between the sitck fixed and stick free static margins as close to 1 as possible or should the differnece in the margins be large?
Thankyou in advance, covid-19 has meant that we're not able to access univeristy resources to gain our knowledge as usual.